# Check if string contains variable name if so add to it

Tags: java

I am not sure if this is possible in java, and know how to code this if this is not possible. However if there is a quicker/more compact way to do this please help me find it.

Allow me to explain what I am doing. I have 20 movies genres (currently just set up as 20 int variables). I also am loading in a bunch of strings, if the string contains a genre (aka if it has "Action") I do action++

However this would require 20 if statments, one for each genre. such as:

```
if(myString.contains("Action")
action++;
```

Was wondering if there was more generic way to do this like this:

```
if(myString.contains(T)
t++;
```

Where T is my genre list.

Is this possible in java?

Comment: Don't use individual variables, use e.g. a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Where are you loading these "genres" from?

Comment: @Julian Using jsoup, also it apears it was a duplicate, I did search just didn't think of typing the word dynamically, which is why it didn't appear for me.

Comment: Use an `enum` for your genres and an`EnumMap<Genre,Integer>` for holding the counts of each genre.

Comment: The key here is understanding that variable "names" don't hold the meaning that you think they do, that what really matters in Java are *references*, and that references often don't have names.